# Weird behaviour RegularExpression in delphi X5

Tags: regex, delphi

I am trying to extract text in the form:

1.The tree has only green apples.

a. the person is boy.

b. the person is a liar.

2.The car drove very fast.

a. it was driven by a mad man.

b. it was by a little girl.

I want the "1.The tree has only green apples." parts of all the paragraphs.
My results list should contain "1.The tree has only green apples.","
2.The car drove very fast"... I have written a regex expression "\d{1,2}.\s(.+?\n\n|.+?$)" and tested on various engines and it works. I can't see why this will not work in delphi xe 5.

Here is the code that I use it from:

```
procedure TForm1.btSearch;
var
  regex: TRegEx;
  i, j: integer;
  mygrps: TGroupCollection;
begin
  regex:= TRegEx.Create(edit1.text);

  mycoll:= regex.Matches(memo1.text);
  if mycoll.Count>0 then
  begin
  label2.caption:= 'Count: ' + IntToStr(mycoll.Count);
      memo2.Lines.Add('First Collection: ');
      for i := 0 to mycoll.Count-1 do
      begin
      memo2.Lines.Add('Match #' + IntToStr(i) + ': ' + mycoll.Item[i].Value);
      memo2.Lines.Add('Group: ' + IntToStr(i));
      mygrps:= mycoll.Item[i].Groups;
           for j := 0 to mygrps.Count-1 do
           begin
           memo2.Lines.Add('Value: ' + mygrps.Item[j].Value);
           end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Delphi at all. Your regular expression is appears to be incorrect. It doesn't match your supplied text in any engine I can find.

Given the following text (from your sample, properly formatted):

```
1. The tree has only green apples.

a. the person is boy.

b. the person is a liar.

2. The car drove very fast

a. it was driven by a mad man.

b. it was by a little girl.
```

The following regular expression matches the two lines you've indicated as your desired result (tested in JGSoft, .NET, PCRE, Java, Perl, JavaScript, XMLSchema, XPath,  and Perl engines):

```
\d{1,2}\.\s.*
```

[image: Screen image of RegexBuddy with above regex and output]

Comment: Thank you very much. Although you gave me the correct expression, try my original regex in any of these: http://www.regexe.com/, http://regexone.com/ and Regular Expressions Tester(Firefox add-on).

Comment: Sorry. Not going to install an unwanted FF add-on to test with, which leaves two I don't know of and explains the "any engine I can find" part of my answer. :) The 9 I tested are the most common, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

When you tested with "various engines", you didn't take into account that various applications and programming languages handle line breaks differently.  In Delphi, `TMemo.Text` returns a string with CRLF line breaks.  To match one such line break in Delphi you need the regex `\r\n`.